# Pass arguments to rendered element from HTML

Tags: reason, reason-react

I have a component that I render on HTML based on class, with the function `renderToElementWithClassName`. I know I can pass values to component in the function (`renderToElementWithClassName(<FAQ param="value" />, "class");`. However, I need to be able to pass it on HTML, as it will be used in various places. Something like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="class" data-param="value" />
</body>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with the code I finally got a hack to do this. Don't know if there's a better way, but this is what I did. You have to put this snippet inside the specific component you want to inject data-attributes:

```
[@bs.val] [@bs.scope "document"]
external querySelectorAll : string => array(Dom.element) = "";

let renderByQuery = (query: string) => {
    let elements = querySelectorAll(query);

    elements |> Js.Array.forEach(e => {
        let yp = (e |> ReactDOMRe.domElementToObj)##dataset##yourprop;
        ReactDOMRe.render(ReasonReact.element(make(~yourProp={yp}, ())), e);
    });
};
```

Then, in your main file:

```
YourComponent.renderByQuery(".custom_class");
```

Now, in your HTML you can use data-attributes according with the ones you've set in the render function.

```
<div class="custom_class" data-yourprop="value1"></div>
<div class="custom_class" data-yourprop="value2"></div>
```

This will render the same component with different `yourProp` props.